# Underline animation on a link

Tags: underline

I want make an underline animation  on a link

this is my html

```html
<header>
        <div class="title">
            <p>feldman</p>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <a href="intro.html">Intro</a>
          <a href="about.html">About</a>
          <a href="fieldman.html">Services</a>
          <a href="project.html">Project</a>
          <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
           
        </nav>
        
           </header>
```

my css:

```css
a::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0%;
    height: 1px;
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover:after{
 width: 100%;   
}
```

the problem is when I put the cursor on the link
all the link is underlined

[the picture of my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwyEP.jpg)

I want a solution to fix the problem  the underline should be only on one link

ok now my css:

```css
 nav a{
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 6px;
        width: calc(100%/5);
        padding: 3px  4px  3px  5px ;
        line-height:1;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        }
        
        nav{
            margin-top: 9px;
            margin-right: 18px;
           
            width: 40%;
            height: 75%;
           display: flex;
           justify-content: center;
           margin: auto 10px;
        }

        header{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there are some other styles in play that aren't included in your code snippet, but at the minimum you'll need to add a `position: relative` to the anchor tags so that the `::after` pseudo-element applies the absolute position relative to the `<a>` rather than whatever the nearest positioned ancestor is.

You'll also need to specify `display: inline-block` on the anchors so that they behave correctly with the injected content.

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7veycqt9/)

Output:

[image: Underlined link]

#### Update to reflect edited question

Since you have padding in the `<a>` styles you can either mess around with the offsets in your `::after` styling (probably not a great idea, then any change needs to be made in two places), or just introduce a wrapper element around the text, e.g.

```html
  <a href="intro.html"><span class="label">Intro</span></a>
  <a href="about.html"><span class="label">About</span></a>
  <!-- etc -->
```

Then apply the `display` / `position` styles to the `.label` element, and update your pseudoelement to hang off the `.label` instead of the anchor.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7veycqt9/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer now is better  but the underline is not only on the word

Comment: @pat66 It's difficult to know precisely what problem you're having given that you have only shared a small portion of your styles.

Comment: i want add a screenshot but i dont know how to add on my comment

Comment: @pat66 updated to reflect your stylings

Comment: with the .label  is worst than before

Comment: @pat66 Terms like "worse than before" do not help anyone to help you. Since you're only sharing part of your CSS and markup then you'll have to adapt the answers back to your code. The [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7veycqt9/1/) that I linked before draws the progressive underline "only on the word" on mouseover, the rest is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try putting the links in a ul tag and then modifying the css with ul { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: left;} and change the width %.